# Clamp using with real_t from Godot-cpp

Tags: c++, godot, clamp

I'm trying to use clamp, but can't find it

A summary example

File: `test.h`

```
#ifndef DEMO_H
#define DEMO_H

#include <algorithm>

namespace demo {

   typedef float real_t;
   class test {
       public:
           void start();
           real_t x = 10.90;
           real_t y = 2.10;
       test();
       ~test();
   };
}

#endif //DEMO_H
```

File: `test.cpp`

```
#include "test.h"

using namespace demo;

void test::start() {
    const int& p = std::clamp(x, 0,  y);
}
```

VSC error, compile using scons:

```
no overloaded function instance "std :: clamp" matches the argument list - argument types are: (real_t, int, real_t)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does your compiler support C++17?

Comment: Requires c++17; can you show the command line used to compile please.

Comment: `clamp` needs c++17. What version are you compiling with?

Comment: Which compiler you are using? Are you building this on Visual Studio?

Comment: Unrelated to error: `x` will be a dangling reference after the line `const int& x = std::clamp(2, 0,  255);` because `std::clamp` returns a reference to one of its parameters, all of which are referencing temporaries that will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression. And so using `x` after that line will cause undefined behavior. Change `const in&` to `int` to obtain the result by-value.

Comment: @walnut Won't this be fine? I thought the `const int&` would extend the lifetime of the temporary. And only if it were `int&` that would be wrong?

Comment: @cigien All references extend lifetimes, not only `const&`, but temporaries cannot be bound to non-const lvalue references. But the problem is that lifetime is extended only once, when the temporary is bound to a reference for the first time. This happens here in the function parameter, i.e. `2` is bound to the first parameter of `std::clamp` ("extending" its lifetime without any real effect), binding to the reference in the return value or `x` then does not further extend the lifetime.

Comment: @walnut Aah, I seem to have misunderstood something then. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The confusion comes from that, I need std::clamp use the real_t

Comment: @walnut I understand, do not notice this detail before (real_t)

Comment: The code is for Godot CPP: https://github.com/GodotNativeTools/godot-cpp/blob/master/include/core/Defs.hpp

Comment: I think the question can be voted to be reopened now. I have done so. However, you should still fix the title, which references a *different* error.

Comment: Ok, I was collaborative a little patience.. I'm trying to define my own clamp function THX!

Comment: The solution: https://github.com/GodotNativeTools/godot-cpp/blob/master/src/core/Color.cpp#L477

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `std::clamp` is declared as follows:

```
template<class T>
constexpr const T& clamp(const T&, const T&, const T&);
```

That means that all three arguments must have the same type. If the template argument is not explicitly specified, then deduction will fail, because successful template argument deduction requires that all function parameters from which a template argument is deduced yield the same type.

But in your example, you use:

```
std::clamp(x, 0,  y);
```

which uses function arguments of type `float`, `int`, `float` in that order. Therefore the first and third function argument will deduce `T` to `float`, but the second one will deduce it to `int`, causing deduction, and thereby overload resolution, to fail.

Make sure that you use the same types:

```
std::clamp(x, real_t(0), y);
```

---

In the line

```
const int& p = std::clamp(x, 0,  y);
```

you are using the wrong type for `p`. I assume that you meant it to be `real_t`, not `int`. You can avoid such type mismatches by using `auto`:

```
const auto& p = std::clamp(x, 0,  y);
```

---

Also, it is not save to store the result of `std::clamp` to a reference if not all arguments to `std::clamp` are lvalues.

`std::clamp` returns one of its arguments by-reference. So it may happen that the second argument `real_t(0)`, which is a temporary, is returned by-reference. But that temporary is destroyed after the line

```
    const auto& p = std::clamp(x, real_t(0),  y);
```

so `p` might be a dangling reference. Instead store the result by-value:

```
    auto p = std::clamp(x, real_t(0),  y);
```

This technically doesn't apply to your line with variable type `const int&`, because the type mismatch between that and the returned reference from `std::clamp` will cause creation of a temporary which will then bind to `p` and be life-time extended. But this is not something one should rely on.

---

In a comment you link you should an alternative implementation for `clamp` as a macro.

A macro here as a significant drawback: It will evaluate its arguments multiple times. If you want a `std::clamp` alternative that accepts different types, then you can write it as a function template yourself, e.g.:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
constexpr auto clamp(const T& t, const U& u, const V& v) {
    return (t < u) ? u : (v < t) ? v : t;
}
```

Note that in this case it is important that the function returns by-value, because the `?:` operator might result in a prvalue depending on the argument types.

Also think carefully about whether you actually want to use `clamp` with different argument types (This applies to both the implementation I show above as well as the macro you are using). You could easily accidentally make unintended comparisons, for example if one of the arguments is a signed integer and the other an unsigned one, the comparison with `<` will yield unintended results. This is probably why the standard library does not allow different argument types.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and for the inconvenience, It is much cleaner, novice error.
A hug!